# How do you type cast Char/Int in Scala?

Tags: scala, casting

I am having issues getting this cast to work.

The compiler tells me value `aNumber` is not a member of object `Char`

```
def runCastTest() {  
  val aNumber = 97  
  val aChar = (Char)aNumber

  println(aChar) // Should be 'a'  
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You are not casting. With `(Char)aNumber` you are trying to invoke a method `aNumber` in the object Char:

```
scala> val aNumber = 97
aNumber: Int = 97

scala> val aChar = (Char)aNumber
<console>:5: error: value aNumber is not a member of object Char
        val aChar = (Char)aNumber
                          ^
```

You can do

```
scala> aNumber.asInstanceOf[Char]
res0: Char = a
```

or as Nicolas suggested call `toChar` on the Int instance:

```
scala> aNumber.toChar
res1: Char = a
```

Answer (score 19):

As everything is an Object in scala, you should use `aNumber.toChar`.

Comment: Your explanation is misleading. One might think that toChar is defined on any object in Scala.